# Obtener coordenadas

Tags: android, geolocalización

Quiero obtener las coordenadas latitud y longitud y almacenarla en un array de string para luego enviarlo a otro intent, sin embargo cuando compruebo si obtengo las coordenadas con un toas veo que están a null.

Marcar la posicion en el mapa lo dejo para otra activity en esta lo que quiero es obtener la latitud y longitud

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String[] coordenadas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Latitud: " + ubicacion()[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Longitud: " + ubicacion()[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void buscar(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Lista.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private String[] ubicacion() {
        this.coordenadas = new String[2];

        this.locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            }, 1);
        }

        Location location = this.locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (this.locationManager != null) {
            if (location != null) {
                this.coordenadas[0] = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
                this.coordenadas[1] = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
            }
        }

        return this.coordenadas;
    }
}
'''
```

Comment: En tu cel estan activados los servicios de Geolocalizacion?

Comment: @Elenasys♦ Estoy usando una maquina virtual para emular un movil, la proporciona por android studio y si tiene la geolocalizacion activada

Comment: Estas obteniendo la ultima localizacion conocida creo que esta es null si es celular es nuevo o si fue reseteado. como es un emulador obvio sera null es como un nuevo cel.

Comment: @OsAndNoTi Aunque suelo usar el emulador, a veces tambien hago pruebas en mi cel y este lleva tiempo sin ser reseteado y despues de leer el comentario de Elenasys♦ probe a ejecutarlo en el movil el cual tiene el gps activado y el resultado es el mismo

Comment: Para aclarar lo que pretendo es obtener la localización actual y en un string[] guardar la latitud y longitud

Comment: @JPillado Es por que no ha guardado todavía una localización, el LocationManager aun no ha guardado nada, para que guarde tienes que obtener la localizacion con la funcion que no trae la de cache, la que usas es como localizacion de cache. Yo nunca he usado esa función ya que es null si el usuario desactiva la lozacion o el cel es nuevo, y eso cuando uso mapa de google uso la misma api de google para obternet la localizacion.